# How to disable ssh login for all users except one?

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, login

I Have ubuntu server 16.04, running on localhost. I want to disable ssh login for all users except `john`. I have tried all answers and comments posted [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/285800/how-to-disable-ssh-login-with-password-for-some-users), nothing works. For example

```
Match User !john
PasswordAuthentication no
```

I put it at the end of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, no empty lines after it, and I restart the server `sudo service ssh restart`. Nothing works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use the following directive and do not need Match section:

```
AllowUsers john
```

Comment: nothing works, tried your answer. Is it because my server is local and tunneling to it? my sshd_config is https://pastebin.com/r0jVxXTg

Comment: @Lynob, your configuration file looks qite strange, If you want I can share the default `sshd_config` file of my Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: yes please share yours, it would be awesome

Comment: Here is how `sshd_config` looks by default: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/D8HRSCNQYK . Here is how my custom file looks like: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FWm2f8Hxfg - only two users are allowed and the password authentication is disabled. The version of my `openssh-server` is `1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4`.